# What is Android 4.0's calendar API?

Tags: android, api

I was looking on googles developer page reference part, and trying to find 4.0's calendar API, as google said there is a new way to handle certain events, but I am not sure how to find it. I did find the MonthDisplayHelper class, but I assume that isn't the API. Does anyone know where I can get that info on the developers site? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an introduction to the new APIs in ICS,

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2011/10/ics-and-non-public-apis.html

And here is the API,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html

There is a section here for events,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html

Comment: No problem at all. You're welcome.

Comment: Actually, I just edited this, I need to rephrase the question. Is this API just for accessing androids built in calendar?